# Inserting space before every capitalized characters for word documents name using power shell

Tags: powershell, ms-word, iteration, rename, doc

I am working on inserting the space before every capitalized characters to rename the word documents in power shell

I tried to insert the space before first character for every file in this folder using the following script in power shell:

Could you pls let me know how to write a script to insert and iterate ?

#Target: the files names will appear as shown here: 220519ColdWaterMeters[enter image description here][1] ,  change all of the file names by adding a spaces in the file names so it will read as “220519 Cold Water Meters”

## previous code

```
PS C:\Users\B> $source_path = "C:\Temp"
PS C:\Users\B> $filter = "*.doc"
PS C:\Users\B> $new_prefix = " "
PS C:\Users\B> $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $source_path -Filter $filter
PS C:\Users\B> # Process each file and add the $new_prefix to the filenames
>>             ForEach ($file in $files) {
>>
>>                 $old_file_name = $file.Name
>>                 $new_full_name = "$($file.DirectoryName)" + "\" + "$($new_prefix)" + "$($old_file_name)"
>>
>>                 # Rename the file (perhaps first with the -WhatIf parameter?)
>>                 # Rename-Item $file.FullName -NewName $new_full_name -WhatIf
>>                   Rename-Item $file.FullName -NewName $new_full_name
>>
>>             } # ForEach $file
```

Comment: Just curious... Why are you doing this script in the consolehost, vs in a PowerShell script editor, i.e., Powershell ISE or VSCode, etc? The conoslehost's defined goal is about interactive commands and running predefined code/scripts, cmdlets, etc. You can always write your stuff in an editor and shell out to the consolehost as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Really, having spaces in filenames, folder names, filed names, property names, is a prescription for unneeded headaches in coding later. Doing so, can/will cause quoting complexities.

Yet, if you really want to do this, try this approach.

```
'220519ColdWaterMeters' -csplit '(?=[A-Z])' -ne '' -join ' '
# Results
<#
220519 Cold Water Meters
#>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-creplace` with delay-bind scriptblock in one pipeline like this.

```
$source_path = "C:\Temp"
$filter = "*.doc"
$new_prefix = " "
Get-ChildItem -Path $source_path -Filter $filter |
    Rename-Item -NewName {($_.basename -creplace '(?=[A-Z])',"$new_prefix") + $_.Extension}
```

Just in case the extension had a capital letter I targeted just the basename and then added the extension back.